# 'next_level_button' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_below (attr) reference

Tags: javascript, java, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

This is my activity_main.xml code

```js
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="next_level_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Click Below to earn points"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and I got an error while creating APK

**Error:(12) error: 'next_level_button' is incompatible with attribute android:layout_below (attr) reference.**

Please help me I want to provide this updated version to my app users :(

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The error is saying that `next_level_button` isn't a proper attribute. What it should be is `@id/next_level_button` to point at your button with the given `id`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with my problem.

Comment: what a error message...